# PYQT5 List Widget Get Item Text

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a list widget generated by QT Designer that I have attached a function to. My project is quite long so I am going to section out the part. Please let me know if you need any additional information. It is a Class.

```
self.importedTagList.itemClicked.connect(self.tagImportListClicked)

def tagImportListClicked(self):
    print("You clicked the widget")
    print(self.importedTagList.itemActivated())
```

So when I click an item on the list widget. The function is called and I see the "You clicked the widget" However I cant seem to figure out how to pull the text from the list widget. I have been looking through some examples and they used item.text() but I cant seem to use that. What should my second print function have to correctly display the item selected on the widget?

Thanks!

Comment: [`itemActivated`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemActivated) is a *signal*, not a function. I suggest you to carefully read what [Signals and Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are, how they work, and how to use them [in python](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots).

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out a solution that works for me.

```
self.importedTagList.itemClicked.connect(self.tagImportListClicked)

def tagImportListClicked(self):
    print("You clicked the widget")
    row = self.importedTagList.currentRow()
    print(self.importedTagList.item(row).text())
```

I realized I had to actually grab the row, then choose the item based on this. This might not be the best solution but it currently works.

Comment: There's absolutely **no** need for that, since the signal already has the item as its argument (as shown in the [documentation of `itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked)). Just add an `item` argument to the `tagImportListClicked` function, and then `print(item)` there.